# How to document return in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, google-closure-compiler, jsdoc, code-documentation

I'm writing my own library for the project at work for a browser application and I am having the same old problem deciding how to comment the code.

I'm trying to follow the [JsDoc](https://code.google.com/p/jsdoc-toolkit/w/list) syntax, but will probably continue the [Google Closure Compiler](https://developers.google.com/closure/compiler/docs/js-for-compiler) way. I may end up using two @return and @returns tags in the documentation, just for portability sake (when I setup the auto-generation of the documentation).

Now, the question, **how do you document the return of a custom anonymous object from a function?** For example:

```
return {
    username: 'username',
    password: 'password',
    enabled:  true
};
```

JsDoc has an example of how a @param can be documented to expect object with certain fields, but not the @returns tag. Similarly, the Google Closure Compiler documentation of a Record Type is vague and has no example to work it out.

Comment: The return type is `Object`. Why don't you simply describe the object structure in a few lines like you would for a parameter?

Comment: See https://developers.google.com/closure/compiler/docs/js-for-compiler#types

Comment: @elusive Yes, I can always do that, the point is to allow for the compiler to have info it can work with, not just for humans to read.

Answer (score 15):

The Closure-compiler uses a subset of the [JSDoc annotations](http://code.google.com/p/jsdoc-toolkit/) (and adds a few of its own). See the [annotation reference for the compiler](https://developers.google.com/closure/compiler/docs/js-for-compiler) for the complete set. A JSDoc annotation is similar to a JavaDoc annotation and is a comment block that begins with `/**` (two stars). While each line of the comment often begins with it's own `*`, that is a convention that is not required. Only one JSDoc tag is allowed per line, but the arguments for a tag can span multiple lines.

The annotation typically applies to the following statement. Here are some examples:

## Variable

```
/** @type {string} */ var a;
```

## Type Cast

```
var b = /** @type {string} */ (window['foo']);
```

*note the extra parenthesis*

## Named Function

```
/**
 * @param {string} bar
 * @return {boolean}
 */
function foo(bar) { return true; }
```

## Function Expressions

```
/** @type {function(string):boolean} */
var foo = function(bar) { return true; }

var foo2 =
  /**
   * @param {string} bar
   * @return {boolean}
   */
  function(bar) { return true; }
```

## Typedef

Complex types (including unions, and record types) can be aliased for convenience and maintainability using a typedef. These annotations can be long, but can be split over multiple lines for readability.

```
/** @typedef {{
 *             foo:string,
 *             bar:number,
 *             foobar:number|string
 *           }}
 */
var mytype;
```

For your original example, there are several possible ways to annotate such a function return value. One of the most specific and still convenient is the record type:

```
/** @return {{username:string, password:string, enabled:boolean}} */
function() {
  return {
    username: 'username',
    password: 'password',
    enabled:  true
  }
}
```

Note the extra `{}`. Also keep in mind that record types will not prevent property renaming.

This annotation tells the compiler that the function returns an anonymous type with `username`, `password` and `enabled` properties. Other valid options would be to define an interface elsewhere and typecast the return value to be that interface. The least specific annotation would be `Object` or `*`.

To see a wide range of possible annotations, take a look at the [extern files in the Compiler project](http://code.google.com/p/closure-compiler/source/browse/#svn/trunk/contrib/externs).

Comment: I actualy read it before asking, and have used the google closure compiler in the past. Still I'm unclear of how to proceed. Imagine the need to document 20 fields in a multiline. Do I put asterisk (*) at the begining of each line? More tests underway.

Comment: The compiler uses JSDoc annotations. I'll update the answer to be more complete.

Comment: @ChadKillingsworth Hi Chad, sorry to barge in on an old thread but this scores high in google `closure annotations multi line`. I'm looking how to annotate complex types with @typedef. The annotation can't be spread out over multiple lines (I think) but it would make a complex typedef more readable. For example `{{hands:number,walk:function(number):boolean,stop:function():boolean ... and lots more ...}}`

Comment: Single annotations can span more than one line. I added an example for typedefs.

Answer (score 5):

One of the nice and portable ways to do it is like the following, using return as a keyword. https://github.com/senchalabs/jsduck/wiki/%40return

```
/**
 * @return {object} return An object with the following properties
 * @return {string} return.username Some username
 * @return {string} return.password Some password
 * @return {boolean} return.enabled Is the user enabled?
 */
function getObj () {
     return {
         username: 'username',
         password: 'password',
         enabled:  true
      };
}
```

If you have to use it in multiple places, you would have to duplicate it, or use `@typedef`, but I haven't figured out how to add comments to `@typedef` so I use something like the following

```
/**
 * @typedef {username:string, password:string, enabled:boolean} MyType
 *  
 *  username: The name of the user 
 *  password: Some password
 *  enabled: Is the user enabled?
 */

/**
 * @return {MyType}
 */
function getObj () {
     return {
         username: 'username',
         password: 'password',
         enabled:  true
      };
}
```

You can also try the suggestion here [How can I document a type in webstorm using just jsdoc?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16609786/how-can-i-document-a-type-in-webstorm-using-just-jsdoc)

Answer (score 1):

If put this in top of the function

```
function myFunction() {
    /**
     * Description of my function
     * @return {!Object.<string, string|boolean>} Returns an object containing username, password and enabled information
     */

    // Do stuff
    return {
        username: 'username',
        password: 'password',
        enabled:  true
    }
}
```

Comment: Or above the function, if you prefer that way of notating. (I always put them inside, so if i do .toString() on a function, i can see the documentation)