# How can I document a type in webstorm using just jsdoc?

Tags: javascript, webstorm, jsdoc

When I write the following code, the annotator tells me that `BrowserSelector` is not defined in the second typedef:

```
/**
 * @typedef {{name: String, minVer: Number, maxVer: Number}} BrowserSelector
 */

/**
 * @typedef {{type:String, browser: BrowserSelector, attribute: Object}} Selector
 */
```

I believe it is not associating the type with the name. How can I do that?

I would prefer not to add actual code for it, just jsdoc comments.

Comment: As of v10.0.4, [`@typedef` still seems broken in WebStorm](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-11189).

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I'm using this comment style for 'struct' like types:

```
/**
 * @name BrowserSelector
 * @property {String} name
 * @property {Number} minVer
 * @property {Number} maxVer
 */

/** @type {BrowserSelector|*} */
var mySelector = {}; // no warning because of '*' in @type :S
mySelector.name = 'foo'; // no warning :)
mySelector.id = 'bar'; // warning :)
```

Comment: That's the structure I am currently using, because Webstorm v8 still doesn't seem to understand @typedef.

Comment: Allegedly, [`@typedef support was fixed](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-11189) but I found it's still not working in WebStorm 10.0.4.

Answer (score 12):

Multiple comments to describe properties is not necessary as of Webstorm 7 (perhaps earlier).

```
/**
 * @name BrowserSelector
 * @type {{
 *     name: String,
 *     minVer: Number,
 *     maxVer: Number
 * }}
 */
```

Comment: Is there a way to comment this format to describe what Name means or is used for?

Answer (score 8):

I recently noticed in the AngularJS source code that they also annotated stuff without any directly attached code. I tried the same principle on your case and came up with the following (even code-completion and type checking work with it in WebStorm):

```
/**
 * @name BrowserSelector
 */
/**
 * @name BrowserSelector#name
 * @type {string}
 */
/**
 * @name BrowserSelector#minVer
 * @type {number}
 */
/**
 * @name BrowserSelector#maxVer
 * @type {number}
 */

/**
 * @name Selector
 */
/**
 * @name Selector#type
 * @type {string}
 */
/**
 * @name Selector#browser
 * @type {BrowserSelector}
 */
/**
 * @name Selector#attribute
 * @type {Object}
 */
```

Comment: It seems that \@propertyOf is not needed, it's inferred from the \@name, webstorm 6.0.2