# Commenting "null" value in javascript

Tags: javascript, comments, jsdoc

What is the right way to comment `null` value in javascript? For example:

```
/**
 * Hides an element.
 * @param {String} id - element id (can be {@code null}).
 * @returns {undefined}.
 */
function hide(id) {

    if (id !== null) {
        document.getElementById(id).style.visibility = 'hidden';
    }
}
```

But the tag `{@code null}` not working...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I document a type in webstorm using just jsdoc?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16609786/how-can-i-document-a-type-in-webstorm-using-just-jsdoc)

Comment: That is not the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Just came across the same issue myself and found that using backticks (``) did the trick for me. Using the JSDoc comment used in your example, it should look like:

```
/**
 * Hides an element.
 * @param {String} id - element id (can be `null`).
 * @returns {undefined}.
 */
```

Answer (score 0):

The proper way to document this function in JSDoc is like the following snippet:

```js
/**
 * Hides an element.
 * @param {String | null} id - element id (can be `null`).
 */
function hide(id) {
    if (id !== null) {
        document.getElementById(id).style.visibility = 'hidden';
    }
}
```